# Need some help in starting with Django

Tags: django

Downloaded Django, ran install, now I need to setup a database -- And I'm stuck. How can I do this? Tried following instructions on-site; no good.

Thanks!

Comment: If you need help setting up a database, this probably belongs to serverfault. If you want to synchronize your models to the database it's just python manage.py syncdb .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The Django Book](http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/) is the best place to start. Django is one of the best documented frameworks I have ever used. There should be no shortage of material for you.

The [Getting Started](http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter02/) chapter specifically has a database section.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see the instructions you followed...

the easiest database to start with is sqlite, all you need to do is put a filename in the DATABASE_NAME setting

so you should have something like this in your settings.py file:

```
DATABASE_ENGINE = 'sqlite3'
DATABASE_NAME = 'dev.db'
```

then in the terminal cd into your project root (the folder with manage.py in it) and run:

```
python manage.py syncdb
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you instruct me how to set up a MySQL DB? The server is already running, but I can't figure out how to connect the two (python and the DB)